# no contact field for JS button in Quote

Tags: button, quote, platform-bug, detail-page

Maybe it's Friday or something, but I have one JS button on detail page for Quotes and I wanted to check if Contact field filled, but as it turned out I can't access it from there.
[image: No contact field error]

And it even isn't listed in field list.
[image]

I found work around. I can just create formula field and get content of Contact field from there, but it's totally weird situation. Does anyone have the same?